What does "best of taste" mean?
This is from a movie: The wife cheating his blind husband with a young lover in front of the blind man( kiss and hug this young dude at the dining table). Later that night they met and this conversation can be heard between them.
Lover:You're wicked
Wife:He couldn't see us
Lover: Wasn't in the best of taste, was it?
His food, his drink, his wife.
So what does "in the best of taste" mean in this context?

Her blind husband!

There's a couple of layers of idiom in this.
First of all not in the best of taste is litotes, or understatement: it means "in poor taste".
Secondly, "taste" in this sense, means "socially acceptable behaviour", but it's a bit more than that. It's almost always used in the negative (which is implied here by the litotes) and it means behaviour which is in some way  a bit offensive or disgusting.
So "It wasn't in the best of taste" means something like "It was rather offensive behaviour".

Thank you very much!

"good taste" means "satisfying generally accepted social or esthetic standards. synonyms: decorous. characterized by propriety and dignity and good taste in manners and conduct." (definition from vocabulary.com
So the best (of) taste is the most proper behaviour.  The lover is speaking with ironic understatement. Kissing you in front of your husband when he can't see was not "the most proper thing to do" (it was very improper).

Thank you very much!
